# Accessing model data with has_many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, has-many

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible  :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :rulesets
end

class Ruleset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :game_id, :user_id

  validates :game_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
  has_many :rules
end

class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :ruleset_id
  belongs_to :ruleset

  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :ruleset_id, presence: true
end
```

I have a controller called PagesController that controls the user dashboard, where I want to display the number of rulesets and number of rules that a user has.  this is my controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  def dashboard
    @rulesets = current_user.rulesets 
  end
end
```

In my dashboard view, I'm attempting to display the rulesets and rules counts as such:

```
<% if current_user.rulesets.any? %>
  <li><%= @rulesets.count %> Ruleset</li>
  <li><%= @rulesets.rules.count%> Rules</li>
<% end %>
```

This returns the right number of rulesets if I just try and count the rulesets.  When I try and count the rules, I get this and "undefined method `rules'" error.  How am I supposed to access the rules that are in the users' ruleset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count all of the rulesets and the rules for each ruleset. Use something like:

```
@rulesets.collect {|r| r.rules.count}.sum
```

Comment: I this case, each ruleset is stored into the |r| object?

Comment: No, rulesets are stored in the @rulesets variable. All the rules for a given ruleset is stores in r as it iterates over the rulesets array.

Answer (score 0):

Rules would be associated to a particular ruleset.  You should specify the ruleset, by id, and then use the ".rules.count" to count all rules associated with THAT ruleset.

Comment: I guess I'm not exactly sure how to do that, since I'm pretty new at this.  I have my collection of rulesets stored in the @rulesets variable in the controller.  How do I go through each ruleset and then extract the rules?